# Avocado lost all but one leaf

Tags: avocado, damage

I am growing two avocado plants which reached about 30cm indoors. I took them outside on a sunny day and then they both suddenly wilted:[image]

Eventually, all the leaves fell off the tallest avocado plant, until there was one left: [image]

There are quite a lot of tiny flies around the avocados too, if this helps.

I really would like my avocados to keep growing tall but the plant doesn’t seem to be growing new leaves.

From the photos, what appears to be the cause of the apparent death of the avocados? How can I fix this problem, especially for the tree with one leaf?

I have managed to grow two healthy avocados - should I resist putting them outside exposed to the sun!
[image]

Comment: How long were they outside and were they in direct sun or in shade?

Comment: Hi, maybe 5-6 hours in direct sun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your plants likely got too much sun, especially if this was their first day outside for the year. When taking indoor plants (or plants that winter indoors) outside as it starts to warm up, you have to start slowly, with just maybe an hour or so for a week and then work your way up. It's also best to start in maybe dappled sunshine under another tree. The sun is way more powerful than your avocados were used to, even if they were right on a window sill!

Since one has one leaf left, it might come back (fingers crossed!). I would just keep it inside and keep up with regular watering and give it some time. I unfortunately did this with a small bonsai I had, but it had no leaves left and it never came back.

For your other two, I would start with just a an hour or so in the morning outside. If they do ok, then you can work your way up to longer.

Comment: Hi Selene, thanks so much for your answer. As regards the other avocado whose leaves are all damaged - is there any way to bring the leaves back to life?

Comment: You could check down at the base of the stem…just nick it with your fingernail to peel back the toughest outer layer. If it’s green in there it has a chance to come back. If it’s just a dried stick then it won’t. I’d just put it back in its windowsill spot and keep watering normally and it may put out new leaves in a few weeks. Fingers crossed for you.